# Sort multiple post values to array group PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array from form with multiple inputs and am trying to group them by table name in field 'name'. Table name i get by explode('-', $item['name']).

I'm trying to group them, but on output my array not looks like array that i need.
My array from form like:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => t_author-f1
        [value] => autho0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => t_author-f6[]
        [value] => author1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => t_author-f6[]
        [value] => author2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => t_title-f21[]
        [value] => 123123
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => t_title-f21[]
        [value] => 123123
    )
```

and now, i need to change array format that:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [t_author] => Array
            (
                [f1] => autho0
                [f6] => author1
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [t_author] => Array
            (
                [f1] => 
                [f6] => author2
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [t_title] => Array
            (
                [f6] => author2
                [f21] => 123123
                [f23] => 123123
                [f23] => 123123
                [f23] => 123123
            )
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [t_title] => Array
            (
                [f6] => author2
                [f21] => 123123
                [f23] => 123123
                [f23] => 123123
                [f23] => 123123
            )
    )
```

i need some help

Comment: I don't understand how you got from that input to that output, could you reword your explanation?

Comment: first array from form $_POST array. Second array is result, that i want to take from first array

Comment: Yeah I know which part is the input and output, but you need to actually explain the process here. How did you get from that input to that output

Comment: What the difference between **2** and **3** in result or **4** and **5** in input data?